# Lubuntu constantly freezing on ibook g4

Tags: lubuntu, macbook, crash, powerpc

I have recently installed Lubuntu on my old Ibook g4.However, every time I boot into it after about 20-60 seconds, the screen **freezes**, **blinks**, and then it **soft locks**. I cannot move the mouse and the keys do not work. It is very hard to fix anything because it crashes as soon as I open terminal.I am pretty sure it is an overheating problem, but I cannot be certain of that.

Comment: What version of Lubuntu?

Comment: 14.04. It is a PowerPC.

Comment: Why not add the `powerpc` tag?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Can you use `ctl + alt + f2` once it freezes?

Comment: No. Any key I press does nothing

Comment: However, I can access it before it crashes